# InputNumber in form item that collects data on enter key and up/down buttons

Tags: antd

Is there a way using the Ant Design library to have an `InputNumber` in a `Form.Item` that only collects the data when the user enters data and presses the enter key or clicks the up resp. down button.

It seems when changing the `trigger` on the `Form.Item` the buttons of the `InputNumber` are not working anymore. Any other way to accomplish that?

Here is a demo that demonstrates the problem: https://codepen.io/medihack/pen/VwvRbpL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to `onClick` events on the `Form.Item` component that wraps the `InputNumber` and programatically change the fields value via a reference to the `form` instance when the up/down buttons are clicked. See example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-euclid-j73k7?file=/src/App.js

Note: I only bothered to demo this approach for the up button, but the solution can easily be extended to the down button.

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, InputNumber } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef(null);

  handleUpClick = (e, ref) => {
    const clickedElement = e.nativeEvent.target.getAttribute("aria-label");
    if (clickedElement === "up" || clickedElement === "Increase Value") {
      const currentValue = ref.current.getFieldValue("number");
      ref.current.setFieldsValue({
        number: Number(currentValue) + 1
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        onValuesChange={values => console.log("values", values)}
        ref={this.formRef}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name="number"
          trigger="onPressEnter"
          initialValue={0}
          onClick={e => this.handleUpClick(e, this.formRef)}
        >
          <InputNumber />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I use a very complex form in "realtime" (by collecting data with onFieldsChange) without ever submitting it. There are some InputNumber fields (inside the same form) that change the form itself. So submit is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: How about  listening to `onClick` events on the `Form.Item` component that wraps the `InputNumber` and programatically changing the fields value via a reference to the `form` instance when the up/down buttons are clicked. See example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-euclid-j73k7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok, this seems to work with the up button. Even if it is a bit hacky ;-) I hoped there would be a more official way using the Ant API. But please post your Codesandbox solution as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.